# ambiguous def with record update syntax

Tags: haskell

Example:

```
data Foo a
   = Foo { fooId :: a
         , fooName :: String
         , fooCount :: Int
         }

instance Default a => Default (Foo a) where
  def = Foo
    { fooId = def
    , fooName = "foo"
    , fooCount = 0
    }

-- this is ok
x :: Foo Int
x = def { fooName = "good" }

-- error, type of def is ambiguous (a could be anything with a Default instance)
y :: Foo Int
y = def { fooId = 2 }

-- ok again
z :: Foo Int
z = (def :: Foo Int) { fooId = 2 }
```

I think I understand why it's ambigouous. That is not the question. Imagine:

```
fooList :: [Foo Int]
fooList =
  [ (def :: Foo Int) { fooId = 0, fooName = "one" }
  , (def :: Foo Int) { fooId = 1 }
  , (def :: Foo Int) { fooId = 2, fooName = "three", fooCount = 42 }
  ...
  ]
```

Instead I would like to write:

```
fooList :: [Foo Int]
fooList =
  [ def { fooId = 0, fooName = "one" }
  , def { fooId = 1 }
  , def { fooId = 2, fooName = "three", fooCount = 42 }
  ...
  ]
```

Does it even matter how GHC infers the type for def in this case? Could be `Foo (Maybe SomethingReallyCrazy)` for all I care. I am overwriting it right then and there into `Foo Int` (or it has to be that to begin with).

I guess defining:

```
defFoo :: Foo Int
defFoo = def
```

would be a workaround, but... it's ugly. Is there a nicer way to do it? Some language extension I'm missing?

Comment: Somehow, I was expecting `\s->s{fooId=4::Int}` to be of type `Foo Int -> Foo Int`, when it actually is of the more general type `Foo a -> Foo Int`. I wonder how often this "feature" is exploited in actual code -- right now I can only spot where it prevents type inference, like in the code above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you've gotten to the root of the problem. All that's left after that is aesthetics.

I can understand the bias against another global binding. How about a local one?

```
fooList :: [Foo Int]
fooList = let def = Data.Default.Class.def :: Foo Int in
  [ def { fooId = 0, fooName = "one" }
  , def { fooId = 1 }
  , def { fooId = 2, fooName = "three", fooCount = 42 }
  ...
  ]
```

You can make that a little less awkward if you're willing to forgo `def` as the record name:

```
fooList :: [Foo Int]
fooList = let d = def :: Foo Int in
  [ d { fooId = 0, fooName = "one" }
  , d { fooId = 1 }
  , d { fooId = 2, fooName = "three", fooCount = 42 }
  ...
  ]
```

As for this

> Does it even matter how GHC infers the type for def in this case?

Sure it does! Suppose someone also defines this in another file:

```
 data MyCustomDataType = Mwahahaha -- note, has no `Default` instance
 instance Default (Foo MyCustomDataType) where
   def = Foo
     { fooId = Mwahahaha
     , fooName = "bar"
     , fooCount = 3
     }
```

And links it against your already-compiled code. Type class instances are global (the "open world" assumption), so their instance is available to your code.

So now, when given `def :: Foo a` for some `a`, there's two possibilities:

- `Default a`, which implies `fooName def == "foo"`.
- `a ~ MyCustomDataType`, which implies `fooName def == "bar"`.

This is an ambiguity it can't resolve.

If you want to close the world - prevent an ambiguity like this from being introduced, you have to tell ghc *how*.

Comment: Oh. I guess I did miss the fact that one can define a Default instance specialized to a given type with different values, although a Default instance for `Foo a` is already defined. Makes sense. Good point, thanks :)